# Non Standard Web Address Format

Tags: warnings, hotmail, yahoo-mail, webaddress

We sent mails to customers in our application which has a link in it. In yahoo and Hotmail, whenever the customer clicks on the link it displays following warning

[alt text http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/5402/warningp.jpg](http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/5402/warningp.jpg)

The URL is long encrypted query string.

Is there any way to suppress this popup?
Or How to intimate the mail server that this is not a harmful site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sri, that's the problem - Yahoo, Hotmail, etc. don't like IP addresses in URLs because they're non-standard and spammers who create spoof emails often use them.

See http://www.myp2pforum.eu/website-forum/10495-when-i-confirmed-my-registration-why-did-i-get-security-warning.html for someone else who had a similar problem to you.

If you're still in testing, you can add a hostname entry for that IP address on your local machine(s) (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file), then you can essentially use a dummy hostname for testing until you get into production.

Comment: http://somepage.aspx?q=lmztrOcXp3AHBuJbuXnirgdtehffr90IrdzoAKZ90HgG30w390QuJNZQEe5DLXmHSTMxe6Km%252fKzmX9jXnjxkoNuItogq4SEQGnY8Fisr60zqgjxvYxe2Aw%253d%253d

This is the kind of query string and the one which i hide in the image is related to yahoo server not to my URL

Comment: Yes, but what is the URL starting with - or is stackoverflow hiding the full URL on this question page?

Comment: if the url does begin with http: // somepage.aspx then that's a reason you'd get the warning right there - you're giving somepage.aspx as the domain (host) of the link; what's the real hostname you intend to give in the message?

Comment: http followed by our own IP. It seems like the problem is with the host as its not yet registered.  Hope Moving to PROD will not raise this problem as its registered. Thanks