# Issue with Base64-encoded parameter in query string

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, hyperlink

I'm sending a link in my web application to users mails (for confirming user registration) as the following :

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost:2817/ConfirmRegistration?confirm=Y0tcmGepe7wjH7A1CT1IaA==">
http://localhost:2817/ConfirmRegistration?confirm=Y0tcmGepe7wjH7A1CT1IaA==
</a>
```

But Chrome alert this message :
[image: Chrome Message]

Is the query string invalid ? How can I resolve it ?

BTW:
My application is in C# and MVC3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non Standard Web Address Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788558/non-standard-web-address-format)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing base64 encoded strings in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should URL encode the `confirm` parameter. The error you get is because of the last `==` fragment.

For this use [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) or similar framework methods.

Comment: I've user `Url.Encode` and the confirm query string changed to `?confirm=Y0tcmGepe7wjH7A1CT1IaA%3d%3d`, but google alert the same message again !

Comment: I had problems with "+" signs being interpreted as spaces so I had to replace the three unsafe base64 chars myself instead, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48441540/236008

Answer (score 9):

I was using HttpUtility.UrlEncode but I had problems if the base64 encoded string contained a "+" sign. It was correctly being encoded to "%2b" but when it was coming back from the browser it was interpreted as a space. So, I used two simple encode/decode methods instead:

```
public static string UrlEncodeBase64(string base64Input)
{
    return base64Input.Replace('+', '.').Replace('/', '_').Replace('=', '-');
}

public static string UrlDecodeBase64(string encodedBase64Input)
{
    return encodedBase64Input.Replace('.', '+').Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '=');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably URL encode the parameter value since `=` is itself used to separate a parameter name from a parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

You can send your value by replacing two char `+` to `_` and `/` to `-`:

```
string confirm=confirm.Replace('+', '_').Replace('/', '+');

<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost:2817/ConfirmRegistration?confirm=@confirm">
http://localhost:2817/ConfirmRegistration?confirm=@confirm
</a>
```

and you can get your data in server side by using:

```
if (Request.QueryString["confirm"] != null && Request.QueryString["confirm"].ToString() != "")
{
       string confirm = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString["confirm"]).Replace('_', '+').Replace('-', '/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.net core you can use WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode and WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode