# PHP base64_decode cannot decode full javascript btoa encode

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a project, where in that project I do base 64 encryption with the btoa () function from javascript then decrypt it using base64_encode () from php, in other files there is no problem but in this file the decryption function cannot decrypt it properly full

this is the code

```
$enc = isset($_GET['g'])?$_GET['g']:'';
$dec = base64_decode($enc);
```

the text : a||`<p>b</p>`||c||t||u||v||d||e|f|g|h|i||j||k|l|m|n||o||p|q|r|s 
encrypted text : YXx8PHA+YjwvcD58fGN8fHR8fHV8fHZ8fGR8fGV8ZnxnfGh8aXx8anx8a3xsfG18bnx8b3x8cHxxfHJ8cw== 
the output after decript : a||`<p> b </p>`

Comment: Have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1374753/2518525), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11206259/2518525)

Comment: How did you form your GET parameter `'g'`? Did you used [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on it?

Comment: just the normal paramter like var link = btoa("the link that i want to encrypt"); and then just location.href= "somelink?g="+link;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the following code to test out. There are at least 2 methods to properly pass `btoa` result to PHP:

```php
<?php

$enc = $_GET['g'] ?? '';

?>

<button type="button">Run</button>
<script>

document.querySelector('button[type=button]').addEventListener('click', function () {
        let str = 'a||<p>b</p>||c||t||u||v||d||e|f|g|h|i||j||k|l|m|n||o||p|q|r|s';

        // Method 1: encodeURIComponent
        window.location.href = '?g=' + encodeURIComponent(btoa(str));

        // Method 2: URLSearchParams
        window.location.href = '?' + (new URLSearchParams({'g': btoa(str)}).toString());
});

</script>

<?php if (!empty($enc)): ?>
        Result: <?=htmlspecialchars(base64_decode($enc))?>
<?php endif; ?>
```